# retrieve 1 or more checkbox value from database

Tags: php

this is my html code

```
   <input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Jaywalking' /> 
Jaywalking<br>

                        <input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Littering' /> 
Littering<br>


                        <input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Illegal Vendor' /> 
Illegal Vendor
```

this is my php code

```
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{   
    $license_save=$_POST['license'];
    $stickerno_save=$_POST['stickerno'];
    $fname_save=$_POST['fname'];
    $mname_save=$_POST['mname'];
    $lname_save=$_POST['lname'];
    $no_save=$_POST['no'];
    $street_save=$_POST['street'];
    $city_save=$_POST['city'];
    $bdate_save=$_POST['bdate'];


    $violationplace_save=$_POST['violationplace'];
    $dd_save=$_POST['dd'];
    $mm_save=$_POST['mm'];
    $yy_save=$_POST['yy'];
    $hh_save=$_POST['hh'];
    $min_save=$_POST['min'];
    $ampm_save=$_POST['ampm'];

    if(is_array($_POST['cbox'])) $violation_save=implode(',',$_POST['cbox']); else $violation_save=$_POST['cbox'];

mysql_query("UPDATE tblcitizen SET license ='$license_save', stickerno ='$stickerno_save', fname ='$fname_save', mname ='$mname_save', lname ='$lname_save', no ='$no_save', street ='$street_save', city ='$city_save', bdate ='$bdate_save',   violationplace ='$violationplace_save', dd ='$dd_save', mm ='$mm_save', yy ='$yy_save', hh ='$hh_save', min ='$min_save', ampm ='$ampm_save', violation ='$violation_save', type ='$type_save', officer ='$officer_save', date ='$date_save', ttime ='$ttime_save' WHERE id = '$id'")
                or die(mysql_error()); 
    echo "<script>alert('Successfully Edited')</script>";
        header("Location: citizen.php");
```

}

I want to edit some account registered, how can i retrieve 1 or more checkboxes value from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED FOR BETTER ANSWER

```
if(is_array($_POST['cbox'])) $violation_save=implode(',',$_POST['cbox']); else $violation_save=$_POST['cbox'];
```

Your query is taking the cbox array, turning it into a string with commas if it is an array (if more than one checkbox was checked), otherwise inserting just one checkbox value with no comma.

To get the values out, just read the string, then compare it with a php strpos()

```
<?
    // Get the checkboxes that were previously selected
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT violation FROM tblcitizen WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         // put the string into a variable
         $mystring = $row['violation'];
      }

    // use a ternary to determine if this checkbox exists
    // if so, make the variable $checked to check the checkbox, otherwise leave it blank
    $checked = (strpos($mystring, 'Jaywalking')) ? 'checked' : '';
?>
    // write the checkbox to the page. and echo the contents of $checked
    // if it was found with strpos() then it will be checked, otherwise it will not be
    // <?= ?> is a quick way to echo a variable without the echo command
    <input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='Jaywalking' <?=$checked;?> />
```

Comment: how can i retrieve my checkboxes?

Comment: please refer to my code. where would i put that code?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Do you want to get the values that were selected? Do you want to put a check in the check boxes that were checked before the UPDATE? Note: this is not the entire code, I didn't add the data pull (getting the data and putting it into a variable)

Comment: You are asking for an entire setup of a page from scratch and we don't know what the page looks like.

Comment: just the checkbox sir, i want that checkbox only to be retrieve. i have a code for the others. i just want the checkbox

Comment: The updated answer should give you what you need, or at least in the right direction. If you were looking for something else, we'll need more information on what your goal is with the information that was inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your sentence of "how can i retrieve 1 or more check boxes value from the database" but since I can see your update statement, I am assuming that you want to take the one or more value from the check boxes and update the table in the database.

1. You will receive the check box value in form of an array
2. You need to loop through the array and get the value
3. Store value in one variable and you are good to go to store it in the database

   ```
   foreach ($cbox as $val) {
       $Violation .= $val.",";
   }
   ```

You can always remove the last comma using PHP substring by the way. Cheers, hope this helps you and anybody out there. Thank You.

Comment: Remove the line of 'if(is_array($_POST['cbox']))...' and put this line

'foreach ($cbox as $val) { $Violation .= $val.","; } ' and echo the value of $Violation to see what you have in the variable.